# Which is the best choice: health, attack, shield or magic?

Tags: infinity-blade

When leveling up, is there a clear best skill to select?

I tried magic at the start but it seems (from reading other forums) that it does not work well at higher levels.

Comment: This is question for Infinity Blade or Infinity Blade II ? The answer is different in function of the game.

Comment: @Ermiar: the first, sorry, is the tag not sufficient?

Comment: As @Wikis used infinity-blade tag, should be for infinity blade game, not infinity blade II. He is not using infinity-blade-series tag.

Comment: My mistake on that. The tag is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is best to level up all skills somewhat equally but, I tend to focus on attack and defense for more power and survivability.

Comment: Isn't that also a reason then also to focus on health? And offensive magic?

Comment: that as well but its just the 2 i go for most with health and magic being third and fourth